# Execution plan vs. ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to fine tune a query that uses a `ROW_NUMBER` with many `PARTITION BY` parameters to get a unique record from the db. The query is exactly like the below:

```
SELECT  SDP.SuspectID                       
        ,SDP.RecordID                   
        ,SDP.Field
        ,SDP.FieldEntryDate
        ,SDP.ScreenDate                 
        ,SDP.SuspectDetails              
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SDP.PeriodEndDate,120) AS PeriodEndDate        
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SDP.recordID, SDP.Field, SDP.ScreenerID, SDP.PeriodEndDate, SDP.PeriodID, SDP.[Source], SDP.SuspectDetails ORDER BY SDP.UploadDate) AS RowNum
        ,SDP.DatabaseAccountCode
        ,SDP.RecordUpdateType
INTO        #Temp
FROM        dbo.SuspectDataPoint
            AS SDP
LEFT JOIN   dbo.Screener
            AS S
            ON S.screenerID = SDP.screenerID                                                            
WHERE       SDP.ScreenerId not in (719)
            AND S.DatabaseName = 'db'
            AND CONVERT(DATE, SDP.FieldEntryDate) > DATEADD(dd,-24,GETDATE())
```

I tried to manually find what the most inefficient parts of this query are and it turned out that it runs >10 times longer with the `ROW_NUMBER` than without it.

I also tried to check the execution plan to confirm that finding, but there is something that I don't understand. If I run the query as it is given above, the execution plan shows me the biggest cost is an insertion to a temp table (45%). This is also the case when I am running the same query without the `ROW_NUMBER` line, just the % differs by a bit (61%). I understand that in the first query, the `ROW_NUMBER` operation happens in `SORT`, but it is considerably inexpensive (25%) compared to the rest. Yet, as I said, the actual time spent without and with the `ROW_NUMBER` line is very different (1s vs. 13s on average). Can anybody explain that to me? Am I reading the plan incorrectly?

[image]

EDIT: adding indexes view

[image]

EDIT: adding schema and indexes scripts

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Screener]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:51 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Screener](
    [ScreenerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ScreenerName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ScreenerDescription] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Script] [text] NULL,
    [HitRate] [numeric](10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [CreatedOn] [date] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](7) NULL,
    [SuspectReason] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [IsExtremeOutlier] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [DatabaseName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ScreenerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint](
    [SuspectID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [RecordID] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Field] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ScreenerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ScreenDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SuspectDetails] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [PeriodEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FieldEntryDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [OriginalValue] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [UniqueSystemID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseAccountCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RecordUpdateType] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [UploadDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [PeriodID] [varchar](20) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SuspectID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [in_n_Screener_DatabaseName]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [in_n_Screener_DatabaseName] ON [dbo].[Screener]
(
    [DatabaseName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [in_n_SuspectDataPoint_DatabaseAccountCode]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [in_n_SuspectDataPoint_DatabaseAccountCode] ON [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]
(
    [DatabaseAccountCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [in_n_SuspectDataPoint_Field]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [in_n_SuspectDataPoint_Field] ON [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]
(
    [Field] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [in_n_SuspectDataPoint_RecordID]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [in_n_SuspectDataPoint_RecordID] ON [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]
(
    [RecordID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [in_n_SuspectDataPoint_ScreenerID]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [in_n_SuspectDataPoint_ScreenerID] ON [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]
(
    [ScreenerID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ScreenDate]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [in_n_SuspectDataPoint_UniqueSystemID]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [in_n_SuspectDataPoint_UniqueSystemID] ON [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]
(
    [UniqueSystemID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [SuspectDataPoint_FieldEntryDate_Index]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SuspectDataPoint_FieldEntryDate_Index] ON [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]
(
    [FieldEntryDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [SuspectDataPoint_RecordUpdateType_Index]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SuspectDataPoint_RecordUpdateType_Index] ON [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]
(
    [RecordUpdateType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [SuspectDataPoint_ScreenDate_Index]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SuspectDataPoint_ScreenDate_Index] ON [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]
(
    [ScreenDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [SuspectDataPoint_Source_Index]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SuspectDataPoint_Source_Index] ON [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]
(
    [Source] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [SuspectDataPoint_SuspectID_Index]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SuspectDataPoint_SuspectID_Index] ON [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]
(
    [SuspectID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [SuspectDataPoint_UploadDate_Index]    Script Date: 10/17/2014 5:53:52 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SuspectDataPoint_UploadDate_Index] ON [dbo].[SuspectDataPoint]
(
    [UploadDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Screener]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Screener_DatabaseInfo] FOREIGN KEY([DatabaseName])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DatabaseInfo] ([DatabaseName])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Screener] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Screener_DatabaseInfo]
GO
```

Comment: Could you add your schema and index setup to the question?

Comment: Oops, sorry, incorrect edit. I don`t see any schema for these two databases in the query, I'll post their indexes shortly

Comment: While images are helpful to get quick overview it would be better to add SQL scripts for tables and indexes. The code can easily be generated by right-clicking on the db and choosing `tasks/generate scripts` and selecting the tables and adding indexes in the advanced dialog on the following tab. You can output to clipboard and just paste it.

Comment: not sure you get notification on my edits; added the requested info.

Comment: I did get a notification, and the added information helps. Will look at it in a while

Comment: The percentage just says how long time the part took within the batch. My guess is that the sort causes all records to be spooled to a temporary table. The extra IO for the temporary table makes all other opertions slower.

Comment: How long does the query take if you eliminate everything but the row number column from the select statement?

Comment: @Jace Hard to tell exactly now, as it seems the server has been under much stress today (checked now and a cpl hrs ago). But it`s a considerable time, I got results around 1:45 vs. 0:03 for selecting everything else but the ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: That's good information. What I'm wondering is whether it would be possible to reduce the partition by clause at all? Maybe re-evaluate the columns you're using now and make sure it's the minimal set of dimensions that you need. Having more than what you need, especially nvarchar(4000) columns, could be part of the slow down.

Comment: Yeah, this situation can be resolved in many ways, and I have already suggested one to the owner of this process. My question here is why there is a discrepancy (as I see it) between the execution plan percentages and the real time taken.

Comment: Sorry I missed the finer point there. I read the beginning "trying to fine tune a query" and my mind stuck with that. I've found that those percentages are just about worthless.

Comment: Is this actual execution plans or estimated?

Comment: It seems there is no difference between estimated and actual, but hard to tell now as things changed elsewhere since I asked this questions and that impacts the plan.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the parallelism bits are skewing the percentages in the execution plan.

On another note, the "Compute Scalar" happens after the parallel sorting in the "with ROW_NUMBER" plan, which probably means that the

```
CONVERT(DATE, SDP.FieldEntryDate) > DATEADD(dd,-24,GETDATE())
```

part of the where clause is happening after the Row_Number OVER clause. If that WHERE clause is excluding a significant portion of the SPD table, that would explain why the OVER clause is so massively affecting the query. You could (have) filter(ed) first and then run the ROW_NUMBER.